# non-full node bitcoin node

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-development

I will like to run a bitcoin node for web3 development, i only want to track transactions within last 30 days max, so i will like to only keep last 30 days of the bitcoin network at any time

is there a solution for this? i dont want or need a full node bitcoin node, this will be used for web3 development to track wallet addresses for current or recent transactions only

please help if you knowledgeable on this solution

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know what you mean by saying 'web3 development', but I suspect that what you'll want to [run is a pruned node](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37496/how-can-i-run-bitcoind-in-pruning-mode) (ie, bitcoin-core with 'pruning' enabled).

What this means, is that you'll have a node that discards older block data that it has already verified as being valid, such that your node will only store a configurable maximum amount of data.

This does mean you'll need to sync the node from the genesis block - after all, doing so is the only way your node will be able to make sense of the current network state (ie, know what is currently a valid transaction / block on the network). Once sync'd, you can configure your node to only store up to a certain maximum amount of data, and you can also configure it to [watch certain addresses for activity](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48633/notifications-to-watch-only-addresses-in-bitcoind) if you'd like.

Comment: web3 development i think i explained it, just write an app that monitors wallet, if new transactions or balance changes etc...so i dont need a full node for that

Comment: @uberrebu: A lot of us in Bitcoin associate web3 with all the ICO, NFT stuff on Ethereum etc. To such an extent that people are using the term "web5" ironically. https://developer.tbd.website/projects/web5/

Comment: so if i want to use this docker image https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-bitcoind what env do i use to run the pruned node mode?

Comment: i just used `bitcoin.conf` file option and added `prune=1024` so i think i should be good..thanks guys for this

Comment: @uberrebu a *full* node is the term for a node that has *fully validated* the current network state. So even a pruned node is a full node in that sense.